# Why do iOS Data Protection delegates getting called unexpectedly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, appdelegate, data-protection

While working in an iOS project, I have configured the [file protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileprotectiontype?language=objc) entitlement to "Protect Until First User Authentication" which means data won't be protected after first unlock after a device reboot.

But I see in the `UIApplicationDelegate` `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` is being called in all cases when device is being locked after unlocked.

Why are my data being protected by iOS without respecting what I configured?

---

<sup>**applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable** - On a device that uses content protection, protected files are stored in an encrypted form and made available only at certain times, usually when the device is unlocked. This notification lets your app know that the device is about to be locked and that any protected files it is currently accessing might become unavailable shortly.
If your app is currently accessing a protected file, you can use this method to release any references to that file. Although it is not an error to access the file while the device is locked, any attempts to do so will fail. Therefore, if your app depends on the file, you might want to take steps to avoid using that file while the device is locked.</sup>

<sup>**NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication** - After the user unlocks the device for the first time, your app can access the file and continue to access it even if the user subsequently locks the device.</sup>

Comment: Have you checked that the entitlement on your profile on the developer portal still matches what you expect it to be? We have found this entitlement changes on its own occasionally. Although usually this leads to a signing error at build time because of the mismatch.

Comment: I have checked and they are matched and if not so there would have been a build error for capability mismatch. @shim